# How to sort multidimensional arrays through a function

Tags: vb.net

I'm having some trouble in vb.net 2012 with sorting multidimensional arrays, I tried to make a custom sorting algorithm to sort the coordinates via the z axis, so that a four sided polygon can be drawn. This is so that the shape can be drawn in order like a z index in css

(also how do you add a thing to the array so that you can define the polygon colour)

```
'there's nothing here in the x and y sections right now
Dim G_ObjList(,,) As Double = {
    {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.95}},
    {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.95}},
    {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.95}},
    {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.95}},
    {{0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}, {0, 0, 0.75}}
}
Function p3DOrder(ByVal a(,,) As Double, ByVal p As Point)
    '0 is point
    '1 is depth
    '2 is distance to p after being translated to p3d (probably only to be used here, but just in case for anyother use)
    'a(depth/point, infopoint
    'create new jagged array (not jagged array anymore)
    Dim avDP(2, a.GetLength(0) - 1)
    'sorts data into new jagged array
    For i = 0 To (a.GetLength(0) - 1)
        'calculate averages and set array
        avDP(2, i) = (Math.Sqrt((a(i, 0, 0) - p.X) ^ 2 + (a(i, 0, 1) - p.Y) ^ 2) + Math.Sqrt((a(i, 1, 0) - p.X) ^ 2 + (a(i, 1, 1) - p.Y) ^ 2) + Math.Sqrt((a(i, 2, 0) - p.X) ^ 2 + (a(i, 2, 1) - p.Y) ^ 2) + Math.Sqrt((a(i, 3, 0) - p.X) ^ 2 + (a(i, 3, 1) - p.Y) ^ 2)) / 4 'calculate distance to main perspective point
        avDP(1, i) = (a(i, 0, 2) + a(i, 1, 2) + a(i, 2, 2) + a(i, 3, 2)) / 4 'set depth side by side with distance calculated
        avDP(0, i) = {New Point(a(i, 0, 0), a(i, 0, 1)), New Point(a(i, 1, 0), a(i, 1, 1)), New Point(a(i, 2, 0), a(i, 2, 1)), New Point(a(i, 3, 0), a(i, 3, 1))}
        'have to keep the varibles in this way to prevent separation between data pairs
        'sort jagged array
        If i <= a.GetLength(0) - 2 Then
            If (avDP(1, i) > avDP(1, i + 1)) Then
                'test switch program
                Dim _tm0() = {avDP(0, i), avDP(1, i), avDP(2, i)} 'temporary stores data to switch
                Dim _tm1() = {avDP(0, i + 1), avDP(1, i + 1), avDP(2, i + 1)}
                avDP(0, i) = _tm1(0) 'switch around array data
                avDP(1, i) = _tm1(1)
                avDP(2, i) = _tm1(2)
                avDP(0, i + 1) = _tm0(0)
                avDP(1, i + 1) = _tm0(1)
                avDP(2, i + 1) = _tm0(2)
                Dim _tmbStep As Integer = 0
                Do While (avDP(1, i - _tmbStep) > avDP(1, i + 1 - _tmbStep)) 'step back if true
                    Dim _tm2() = {avDP(0, i - _tmbStep), avDP(1, i - _tmbStep), avDP(2, i - _tmbStep)} 'temporary stores data to switch
                    Dim _tm3() = {avDP(0, i + 1 - _tmbStep), avDP(1, i + 1 - _tmbStep), avDP(2, i + 1 - _tmbStep)}
                    avDP(0, i - _tmbStep) = _tm3(0) 'switch around array data
                    avDP(1, i - _tmbStep) = _tm3(1)
                    avDP(2, i - _tmbStep) = _tm3(2)
                    avDP(0, i + 1 - _tmbStep) = _tm2(0)
                    avDP(1, i + 1 - _tmbStep) = _tm2(1)
                    avDP(2, i + 1 - _tmbStep) = _tm2(2)
                    _tmbStep += 1 ' continue step back
                    If (i - _tmbStep < 0) Then 'stops error
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'return resorted array
    Return avDP
End Function

Me.Canvas.Image = New Bitmap(Me.Canvas.Width, Me.Canvas.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Me.Canvas.Image)
        Dim mainPP = New Point(Me.Canvas.ClientRectangle.Width / 2, Me.Canvas.ClientRectangle.Height / 2)
        For i = 0 To (G_ObjList.GetLength(0) - 1)
            Dim _tmpy() As Point = {
                p3d(G_ObjList(i, 0, 0), G_ObjList(i, 0, 1), G_ObjList(i, 0, 2), mainPP),
                p3d(G_ObjList(i, 1, 0), G_ObjList(i, 1, 1), G_ObjList(i, 1, 2), mainPP),
                p3d(G_ObjList(i, 2, 0), G_ObjList(i, 2, 1), G_ObjList(i, 2, 2), mainPP),
                p3d(G_ObjList(i, 3, 0), G_ObjList(i, 3, 1), G_ObjList(i, 3, 2), mainPP)
            }
            Dim br As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, G_ObjList(i, 0, 0) * 0.3, G_ObjList(i, 0, 0) * 0.3, G_ObjList(i, 0, 0) * 0.3))
            g.FillPolygon(br, _tmpy)
        Next
end using
'be aware that this isn't all the code
```

Comment: Much much easier to create an X-Y-Z class, put them in a list and sort it in one line: `sorted = myPoint.OrderBy(Function (j) j.Z).ToArray()`  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: If you think that you need to sort a 2D array then you almost certainly shouldn't be using a 2D array in the first place.  If each "row" in the array represents a single entity then you should use an existing type or define your own to represent that entity and then create a 1D array of that type.

Comment: That said, even if you do use a 2D array, there's no need for a custom sorting algorithm.  You would use the exact same algorithm as you would if you were sorting a 1D array.  Any such algorithm is going to consist of repeatedly comparing two elements and then rearranging them if appropriate.  You would do exactly the same thing here.  The only difference would be that, for each "row", you compare values from one "column" but then rearrange values from all "columns".  If you must use a 2D array, try implementing something like quick sort for a 1D array and then make the simple adjustment.